# How to learn why an HTML element is disabled

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to use an open source HTML5 file uploader snippet in one of my pages, and have put (I believe) all the correct javascript in place.

However, when the page loads I see the 'choose file..' button along with the text box that shows the path to the file on my hard drive, and they're both greyed out.

In looking through the Google and FireFox development tools I can't see why this would be; the CSS involved is quite involved and I can't tell easily whether there's a block display of hidden in there, or whether something else is disabled.

Nothing's jumping out.  Are there HTML or CSS inspectors that can help figure out why HTML element X is disabled?

Comment: That HTML5 file uploader probably only allows specific file format... Double check file formats allowed

Answer (score 1):

There should be a `disabled` attribute set. You can try two things:

- Check the HTML by viewing the source code. This is the HTML rendered before JavaScript.
- Check the Dev Tools and look for a `disabled` attribute. Then check your JavaScript.

It is hard to debug this remotely but this should send you on your way.